# Axis.Minimum keeps getting rounded C#

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I'm trying to implement a lateral chart move by dragging it with the mouse:

```
private void chart1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    xDown = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X);
}

private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
    double range = ax.Maximum - ax.Minimum;
    double xv = ax.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X);
    double ToMove = (xv - xDown);

    ax.Minimum -= ToMove;
    ax.Maximum = ax.Minimum + range;
}
```

Both the maximum and minimum values are being written to without problem. Somewhere in the charts update method the AxisX.Minimum property is being Floored to and integer (this does not happen to the AxisX.Maximum property). Is there any way to stop this from happening? I have tried changing the axis Interval, IntervalAutoMode and a variety of other properties with no success.

Comment: You have verified that both the `Minimum` and `Maximum` properties are being assigned the values you expect, and that those values' types are both `Double`?  Correct?

Comment: I have verified this. When the Minimum value is set (example: ax.Minimum = 1.2) the value persists until the MouseMove method is finished. When the method MouseMove is called next the value is truncated to an integer (example: get Minimum returns 1)